# Print two arrays on same line

Tags: java, loops

I'm sure this will be a simple question but I can't seem to find the right answer. I have two distinct String arrays, each with data and each have exactly the same array length (21). I'm simply trying to loop through both indexes and print index value 0 for array 1 and index value 0 for array 2 on the same line and so forth.

Here's what I have. I have one array called weightToOunce and another called weightArray. The problem with this code is it's based on the length of both arrays so each index value within the array is printed the length of the array (21 times in this case).

I've tried moving the print statement out of the loop and declaring an int i and int j variable before the loop but I haven't been successful there either.

```
public static void weightArrayLooper() {
    String[] weightToOunce = Project1.setWeightPercentageToOunce();
    for (int i = 0;i<weightArray.length;i++) {
        for (int j = 0;i<weightToOunce.length;j++) {
            System.out.println("Lb " + weightArray[i] +  " Oz " + weightToOunce[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: plz share your current output and desire output

Comment: I've edited my function and this is what I have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but you can use the same 'i' value to traverse both array!

```
public static void weightArrayLooper() {
    String[] weightToOunce = Project1.setWeightPercentageToOunce();
    for (int i = 0;i < weightArray.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Lb " + weightArray[i] +  " Oz " + weightToOunce[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Also, you should use `String.format()` instead of concatenating all these variables:

`System.out.println(String.format("Lb: %s; Oz: %s", weightArray[i], weightToOunce[i));`